# Hibernate Too Many Connections With Cache

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, connection-pooling, ehcache

I'm using hibernate to try and retrieve a cached query.

```
@Transactional
public interface ProductDAO extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    @QueryHints({ @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true") })
    Product findByCode(String code);
}
```

I'm load testing and I'm doing this in a large loop of 1000 iterations.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            URL myURL = new URL("http://localhost:8080/test");
            URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
            myURLConnection.connect();
            myURLConnection.getContent();
        }
```

I've checked with showsql and I can see only 1 SQL statement is generated for my first hit to the DB after which it is cached.

Yet I still get the following error even though no SQL is being shown:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections
```

My Hibernate properties:

```
#hibernate properties
hibernate.dialect = ${hibernate.dialect}
hibernate.show_sql = false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = ${hibernate.hbm2ddl}
hibernate.c3p0.min_size = 10
hibernate.c3p0.max_size = 100
hibernate.c3p0.timeout = 300
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements = 50
hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment = 5
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period = 3000

hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
```

Database config:

```
<bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${hibernate.dialect}" />
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="jpaProperties" ref="hibernateProperties" />

    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <array>
            <value>com.exammple.model</value>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:/spring/hibernate.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" factory-bean="entityManagerFactory" factory-method="getSessionFactory" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.example.dal" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
    transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" repository-impl-postfix="CustomImpl" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your configuration you aren't using a connection pool.

You are configuring a `DriverManagerDataSource` which isn't a proper connection pool. You are injecting this bean into the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` which renders your `hibernate.connection` and `hibernate.c3p0` properties useless, they aren't used.

Solution is quite easy drop the `hibernate.c3p0` and `hibernate.connection` properties and replace the `DriverManagerDataSource` with a proper pool implementation. I would recommend [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) over C3P0 but that is personal preference.

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">${db.url}</prop>
            <prop key="user">${db.username}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${jdb.password}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>
```

Comment: This works..the default settings seems to accept 10 connections but then it waits around 30 seconds before continuing. Not sure why the connections aren't being closed by Spring/Hibernate...

Comment: M. Deninum Is there a way to contact you about consultancy work?

Comment: Make sure you have correctly setup your transactions, also why do you have a `SessionFactory` and how are you obtaining sessions from that (if you are using it that is).

Comment: For consultancy you can drop me an email at **marten[dot]deinum(at)conspect[dot].nl** (sorry for the cryptic bit).

Comment: Did you get my email?

Comment: Yes, but we are in the middle of going live so things are a bit frantic.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be have multiple issues:

1. You don't close your database connections.
2. You set a maximum [connection pool](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-connection-pooling/) pool size that exceeds the maximum connections allowed of your database server. When the number of clients exceeds the number of maximum allowed connections, you'd get an exception like this.

I could use [FlexyPool](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/flexy-pool) to monitor the connection pool usage and find out if connections are leaking or if they are leased for long times.

### Update

As M. Deinum already said, you are not using Connection Pooling.

You can still use the Hibernate C3P0 properties, but you have to remove the `dataSource` from the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`:

```
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
```

This way Hibernate can use the `hibernate.c3p0` properties.

Comment: Isnt it complaining about "Too many connections"? Also I was under the impression that each visit to the page will be in its own transaction.

Comment: How do you know I am not closing my transactions? You can only see the client http test code. That code could be used for any website. The code above has nothing to do with database connections.

Comment: I use spring data jpa which handles all the transactions automatically. Also using c3po pool.

Comment: Maybe the connection pool has a maximum size which is greater than the one supported by your DB. During load testing, you could bump into this issue.

Comment: I updated the answer with some possible scenarios. If you are using a connection pool, try FlexyPool to get an insight into your application connection allocation usage patterns.

Comment: I added the Spring JPA code above. As you can see its transactional. What I don't understand is if the query is being cached and is transactional why is it opening so many database connections? I can't even see any SQL being sent apart from the first query.

Comment: I need the `EntityManagerFactory` configuration and especially the `DataSource` part.

Comment: I've added a separate question regarding why Hibernate is hitting the database in the first place: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959253/hibernate-cached-load-by-naturalid-creating-database-connection